# How to deploy a blog made using Sphinx

Tags: python, blogs, python-sphinx, ablog

I made a blog using Ablog, a plugin for Sphinx that lets you build a complete blog with analytics, disqus integration etc.

I want to deploy this app, I tried heroku but it didn't work. Has anybody deployed a blog using Ablog, or Sphinx?

Thanks

http://ablog.readthedocs.org/

http://sphinx-doc.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `ablog build` generates a static site, and deploying it should be as easy as copying the generated files into a directory that a web server is configured to serve. I have a similar setup using Pelican for my blog and I use [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) to deploy it, which means creating a git repo with the correct name (*username*.github.io), adding your generated files, and pushing it up, after which your blog will be available at *username*.github.io.

Comment: The static html files generated by `ablog build` are, by default, created in a sub-directory called `_website`.  Just copy this folder to your web server as suggested in the answer above